# Wordpress is very slow, even it's not opening sometimes

Tags: performance

I have migrated a WordPress site from the old server to my new server now it's very slow and even some times it's not opening at all. I'm not getting any error message just a blank page I'm getting. Please help me to fix that issue.

Comment: Can you check the server's CPU and memory usage - is it running up against any limits? Ditto the database server if that's hosted separately. If you can SSH into the machines you can check this with `top`. You should also check your server's error log, and PHP error log if different, and it's worth looking at the syslog (/var/log/messages) too for anything that's relevant.

Comment: Or if you can ask your host for help then I suggest you do that too - you're not happy with your new server after all.

Comment: CPU and memory utilization is almost negligible. There no load only site is slow that's it.